# Encrypting home directory on Raspberry pi with password file on USB

Tags: raspberry-pi, encryption, raspbian, ecryptfs

I have been trying to follow this guide: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-encrypt-directories-and-partitions-with-ecryptfs-on-debian/ to encrypt the home directory on my pi with out a password by saving the password on a file onto a usb. But the issue is that the pi boots up to a login screen and prompts for a password. The only difference to the configuration in the guide I have made is that my usb is ntfs and the name of the directory that is being encrypted (pi) and the password. I tried it again and afterwards when the pi booted up it said root account was locked and I only had command line access to the system.

Are there any passwordless encryption alternatives that I can use? As the pi will have a display but no keyboard.

Comment: This might be a use case for writing custom firmware.

Comment: To be honest I don't think I am capable of doing that, but could you expand on that idea?

Comment: Perhaps the use of ntfs, which is a fuse filesystem, is finished asynchronously and so not ready when the ecrypfs starts. Are you using `mount -a` in `/etc/rc.local`? Perhaps do it with 2 explicit mount commands (`mount /dev/sdb1;sleep 2;mount /home/pi`). Doesnt raspian auto mount entries in fstab? If so add option `noauto` to the 2 fstab entries.

Comment: Yes I was using mount -a, just tried the two separate mounts and it made no difference. Also added the noauto for the two entries.

Answer (score 0):

What are firmware name and version that you was deployed on your Raspberry?

```
Some keyboards are not be supported by Raspberry firmware. (caused by driver or power supply is not enough)
```

and

```
Some firmware version don't support generic keyboard.
```

==> Confirm the encoded password and input from keyboard are right!
I've used armbian for my lab and it's running stably.

Comment: I'm using raspbian Jessie x86. But I realized why you are commenting about the keyboard. I meant that the device will only have a display, as in no keyboard or mouse will be attached to the device.

Comment: To be honest I have not tried it, I didn't think it would be an issue but I can try to reformat another USB to vfat and try it tomorrow.

Comment: Did you tried with vfat successfully? Let show the content of /etc/fstab with the line mount ntfs usb.

Comment: Here is the /etc/fstab content (sorry about the formatting - it won't let me add extra lines):                                                              /dev/sdb1       /mnt/usb        ntfs    ro      0 0
/home/pi /home/pi ecryptfs defaults 0 0

Comment: Try ntfs-3g: /dev/sdb1 /mnt/usb ntfs-3g permissions 0 0    (Note that: vfat do not have its own permission policy --> ro option is not real readonly.)

Comment: Just tried it and I am still stuck at the GUI login screen not being able to login.

Comment: Let try with fat usb format, mount usb (vfat) first then mount your home directory.

Comment: Just tried with fat and it made no difference, also tried making a new user account and it also made no difference. So I am just going to stop up since I can't find any solutions in a suitable manner of time.